# BotoServerError: 400 Bad Request: Mail is not sending

Tags: python, django, amazon-web-services, boto

```
from datetime import datetime as dt, timedelta, date
from django.conf import settings
from django.core.mail import send_mail
from django.core.mail import EmailMultiAlternatives
from django.core.management.base import BaseCommand, CommandError
from hive.apps.accounts.sms_utils import send_sms_twilio



to_email = ['admin@domain.com']
subject = 'Your subject here'
email_body = 'The following clients are currently eligible for Test.Please contact them .<br>'


msg = EmailMultiAlternatives(subject, '', settings.DEFAULT_FROM_EMAIL, to_email)
msg.attach_alternative(email_body, "text/html")
msg.send()
```

When i run this code on centos with AWS instance.i am getting following error



```
 BotoServerError: 400 Bad Request
  <ErrorResponse xmlns="http://ses.amazonaws.com/doc/2010-12-01/">
  <Error>
  <Type>Sender</Type>
  <Code>RequestExpired</Code>
  <Message>Request timestamp: Wed, 01 Oct 2014 07:35:22 GMT expired.  It must be within 300 secs/ of server time.</Message>
  </Error>
  <RequestId>c79a9723-493c-11e4-b2d8-51a7cb197196</RequestId>
  </ErrorResponse>
```

while its working on another AWS instance.

I have Tested following possibilities.

1. Server date and time.
2. simple mail is also not working:
   send_mail('your subject',str(e), settings.DEFAULT_FROM_EMAIL,                          fail_email , fail_silently=False)

Comment: well the error is saying that your email request timestamp is more than 5 minutes off so possibly time drift? what is the output of `date` on the server.

Answer (score 1):

That error indicates your server time isn't synced with Amazon's server's time...

you can check the time of Amazon's server by running:

```
wget -S "https://email.us-east-1.amazonaws.com"
```

look for the timestamp in the returned message. replace us-east-1 with your appropriate regional endpoint.

Compare that to your system's time...

if you need an NTP server, you can use:

```
0.amazon.pool.ntp.org
1.amazon.pool.ntp.org
2.amazon.pool.ntp.org
3.amazon.pool.ntp.org
```

if this is in one of your own Amazon VPCs, you can set a DHCP option set on the VPC with those ntp servers specified.  If your server still isn't syncing, make sure you don't have a security group blocking ntp (UDP 123).

Answer (score 0):

In my case my Ubuntu server was out of synchronization with SES backend and returned me the same message. To solve it:

1. Check the time on SES and your local time: Checking SES time with
   `wget -S "https://email.eu-west-1.amazonaws.com"` Change the link depending on you email endpoint.
2. Check time on your server with `date`
3. If they are different install ntp on server with `sudo apt-get install ntp`
4. And finally syncronize your server time:

`sudo service ntp stop 
sudo ntpdate -s time.nist.gov
sudo service ntp start`